# ElasticSearch collapse

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that brings back two different types of documents (A, B).
I need to do a field collapsing on document type B (`file_content.file_id`)

This works ok but unfortunately instead of having all the documents from type A the field collapse functionality chops the results. The field that I collapse on does not exists on document type A documents.

Any ideas how I will have my results include all documents of type A (similar to no field collapsing applied) while at the same time I apply field collapse on documents of type B?

I would expect that since the field collapse does not exists at all on documents with application type A then no collapsing should have been applied on them.

Both documents live on the same index since they have a parent-child relation.

In order to be more specific. Documents on type B contain `file_content.file_id` while this does not exists on documents with type A.

UPDATE:

I found this [link](https://www.rea-group.com/blog/using-elasticsearch-field-collapsing-to-group-related-search-results/) where the person seemed to have the same issue with me. If you look at the **first** bullet point of the **Additional Issues** you will notice that this person had to include dummy data in order NOT to collapse his documents that did NOT include the field that he was collapsing on.

Comment: How about a [multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)? one single request containing one search for documents of type A and another for type B with collapse

Comment: Hi @Val thank you for the comment. With mutli-search we loose pagination/sorting? We receive many multiple results as I understand. Is it normal that the field collapsing is applied on documents with type A although this field does not exists?

Comment: Would you mind showing your query?

Comment: Val I have updated my query description. I am thinking of including dummy data in order to have the correct results. I can see from the aggregations that the search results are correct but due to the field collapsing it returns only one document of type A. If I remove the field collapsing then I have all the correct results for documents of type A. I would expect that if the field is NOT present then ES should return ALL the documents. Do you have any other better solution ? I use 6.2.4. I will add a sample query as well as you asked.